# Singleton Pattern: Can't see class that is declared in Form

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, singleton

I have Singleton Pattern of `Form1`:

```
private Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private static Form1 _Instance;
        public static Form1 Instance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Instance == null)
                    _Instance = new Form1();
                return _Instance;
            }
        }
```

Also, I have next class that is declared in main form `Form1`:

```
public class Question
    {
        public Question(string q_text, Dictionary<string, bool> ans)
        {
            text = q_text;
            answers = ans;
        }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, bool> answers { get; set; }
    }
```

But, when I in form `EditQuestions` want to declare such dictionary: `Dictionary<int, Form1.Instance.Question> quest = quest = Form1.Instance.questions;`  , it underlines `Question`   . The Point is that in Form1 I have some questions. And in `EditQuestions` form I want to edit questions. In `Dictionary<int, Question> questions` I save these questions. I think that I can edit questions in `EditQuestions` form and then assign edited dictionary to `Dictionary<int,Question> questions` in `Form1`

Comment: Can you post how `.questions` property is declared, code where it is used and VS highlights it, as well as the error message that VS gives for the highlight? You're missing relevant info in your question to analyze it properly.

Comment: `Form1.Instance.Question` seems to be a property (or field). But you need to declare a Dictionary with *types* (a-ka the data type of the keys and the data type of the values). What is the type of `Form1.Instance.Question`? Is it the Question class? Or maybe, is Question a nested class, a-ka Form1.Question?

Answer (score 0):

The issue lies in the definition of your dictionary.

```
Dictionary<int, Form1.Instance.Question> quest
```

Here you are actually asking for a reference to  Form1's Question member, but Form1 doesn't have a member called Question. What Form1 does have is a nested type of Question. For the definition of the Dictionary you need a Type rather than an object reference.

Change your Dictionary to be this and it should work

```
Dictionary<string, Form1.Question> quest
```

Additionally, if you're using .NET 4 or up, a much cleaner and safer way to create a singleton is to use the Lazy class, like so

```
private static readonly Lazy<Form1> SingletonInstance = new Lazy<Form1>(() => new Form1());

private Form1()
{
}

public static Form1 Instance
{
  get { return SingletonInstance.Value; }
}
```